# How to automatically set all links to nofollow in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nofollow

I know I can pass `:rel => "nofollow"` to `link_to` but is there a way to set that by default so I don't have to make changes in each `link_to` tag?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your application helper you can override the `link_to` method and replace with your own.

```
def link_to(name, options = {}, html_options = {})
  html_options.merge!(:rel => :nofollow)
  super(name, options, html_options)
end
```

Comment: In case you don't want to overwrite any `rel` values already on your link, try using `merge_nicely!` instead: https://gist.github.com/joshuapinter/78a5545d713ab9d55883

Answer (score 2):

You could create an alias to the old `link_to` then override it so it calls the old alias with the extra parameter. That way, you don't have to change all the existing `link_to` in your code.