# How to force rails to create links to the www subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `partners` subdomain which serves content using a controller.

The urls are like: `http://partners.example.com/...`

**Is there a way I can force all `_path` and `_url` functions to return links to the root `www` subdomain?** Since the resources my links refer to are not on the subdomain itself and only on the root domain (and I don't want to serve duplicates).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Rails 3.1, it can be done with:

```
resource_url(:subdomain => 'www')
```

But, the helper resource_path does not accept the subdmain key.

Comment: `root_url(subdomain: 'www')` also works when needing to get to the home page of a subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to my answer here: [How to automatically set all links to nofollow in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533067/how-to-automatically-set-all-links-to-nofollow-in-rails/3533157#3533157)

Instead of no-following (like in my other answer), you could:

```
def link_to(name, options = {}, html_options = {})
  html_options.merge!(:host => with_subdomain("www"))
  super(name, options, html_options)
end

def with_subdomain(subdomain)
  subdomain = (subdomain || "")
  subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
  [subdomain, request.domain, request.port_string].join
end
```

with_subdomain method is from http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Answer (score 2):

I'd set the `default_url_options` to include your main host:

```
ActionController::Base.default_url_options = {:host => '...'}
```

The options you pass to `link_to` will override these but, as the name suggests, this allows you to provide default values.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent rails cast on this subject here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Your question was too vague without actual code snippets of your controller requests.

This should get you your answer though.  Just customize to your needs.